# Get access to web storage functionality when window.localStorage is overwritten

Tags: javascript

My code is running in an environment where `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` is replaced with custom implementations. It is done by [sessionbox](https://sessionbox.io/) browser extension like this:

```
Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", new (function () {...})());
Object.defineProperty(window, "localStorage", new (function () {...})());
```

How I can get access to original `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` in this case? I tried to do this through `Storage` object, but without success.

Comment: "Im my code localStorage and sessionStorage is replaced with custom implementations." Please do not do that (unless it is for polyfilling).

Comment: @str Actually it is done by chrome extension (sessionBox) and I have to find way work in this enviroment.

Comment: @SergeyNovikov Did you try referencing it before ovverrding ?

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I cant since my code is excuted after extension code and I cant change this behaviour.

Comment: @ꜱᴜʀᴇꜱʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ Also, if I reference it before overriding after overriding my reference will refer to the new object so I can not use it. Am I wrong?